# Cannot install openproject in Windows7 64 bit - undefined method `dlopen' for Fiddle:Module

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, openproject

I cannot install openproject in my system, i have followed all the steps mentioned in the openproject wiki document

I have Windows 7 64 bit and
installed ruby using `railsinstaller 2.2.4` from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/railsinstaller/Windows/railsinstaller-2.2.4.exe)
mysql `mysql-5.6.21-winx64` from [here](http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.21-winx64.zip)
`mysql 32 bit clien`t from [here](http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.5-win32.zip)
`openproject` from git [location](https://github.com/opf/openproject.git)
Followed document from openproject [guide](https://community.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Installation_Windows).
i am getting following error,kindly guide to get rid of this issue.
I am very new to Ruby

```
C:\Users\Administrator\openproject>bundle exec rake db:create:all
require 'rails/all'... 2.309s
Bundler.require... rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `dlopen' for Fiddle:Module
C:/Users/Administrator/openproject/config/application.rb:68:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Users/Administrator/openproject/config/application.rb:44:in `block in bench'
C:/Users/Administrator/openproject/config/application.rb:43:in `bench'
C:/Users/Administrator/openproject/config/application.rb:67:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/Administrator/openproject/Rakefile:33:in `require'
C:/Users/Administrator/openproject/Rakefile:33:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: One of the OpenProject maintainers here. You are very brave to install OP on windows. Please note that we don't officially support windows (I am no windows-guy myself). I heard rumours that some people got it to work on windows. But for any kind of support, please install it on a linux (e.g. debian) system.
If you still want a windows installation, my best guess is to remove `unicorn` from the Gemfile.

Comment: +1 because you're brave and I like to see answers :)

Comment: @tessi I already removed unicorn, because kgio will not support windows, i read this in some forum and i removed, i got the above error after removing Unicorn, i tried to install openproject in Oracle Linux i got different error, i will post that error in another question and update you.

Comment: https://community.openproject.org/topics/3096

Comment: This issue got resolved with the of @Matin.
I have another problem in last step of openproject installation in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409413/sprocketsfilenotfound-couldnt-find-file-jquery-openproject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not appear to be a problem with openproject, but rather one with the [railsinstaller version you are using](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/issues/223). It will go away when you make sure you're using a ruby version above 1.9.3

The [openproject installation guide](https://community.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Installation_OpenProject_3_0#31-Requirements) lists ruby 2.1 as a minimal requirement. Unfortunately it seems that there is no railsinstaller that provides a ruby above 1.9, that would render openproject incompatible with railsinstaller on your machine.

Comment: I accept this problem raised due to ruby 1.9, Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to try the [railsinstaller-windows 3.0.0-alpha2](https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/releases/download/3.0.0-alpha.2/railsinstaller-3.0.0.exe) with Ruby 2.0.0. Obviously this setup is can not be recommended for production but at least you might be able to get everything running.

Comment: Are the two comments above auto-reviewing for first posts? To me it sounds like they are not connected to the answer. I think this answer is a good one, as it's ruby 1.9 which causes the OP's error.

Comment: I have installed railsinstaller-3.0-alpha, but while installing mysql2 i'm getting the following error, please guide ,is there any version conflict or any thing else ...... 
**make
generating mysql2-i386-mingw32.def
compiling client.c
client.c: In function 'rb_connect':
client.c:331:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code**

Comment: @JackVimal are you sure this is the error causing your problem. The **warning** you mentioned shouldn't be responsible for not getting mysql2 installed.

Comment: I solved that issue, i used 64 bit mysql connector, when i used 32 bit , i can able to install mysql2, Thanks for sharing railsinstaller 3.0 - alpha