# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery' openproject

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, openproject

I tried to install openproject in windows 7 64 bit.

I followed the steps mentioned in openproject wiki, but cannot install it successfully, see the error log

```
openproject>bundle exec rake assets:precompile
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
require 'rails/all'... 1.887s
Bundler.require... 4.181s
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansic
on/) to get coloured output on Windows
Application.initialize!... [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will defa
ult to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale
you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
13.447s
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery'
  (in C:/OpenProject/openproject/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb:13)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

when i tried [**this Stakeoverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285873/couldnt-find-file-jquery-in-rails-project) solution i got the following error

```
openproject>bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
require 'rails/all'... 1.934s
Bundler.require... 4.321s
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansic
on/) to get coloured output on Windows
Application.initialize!... [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will defa
ult to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale
you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
13.135s
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-migrate/jquery-migrate'
  (in C:/OpenProject/openproject/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb:14)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Now i was cornered in last step of the installation. Any one Help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just a guess, but from what I can see in the OpenProject source, there is a bower.json. Did you run `bower install`?

Comment: i don't see any bower.json in openproject folder, i checkedout stable branch of openproject

Comment: I checked out dev version, then i got bower.json, Thanks to @Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery-migrate was added in [dcde12a2277](https://github.com/opf/openproject/commit/dcde12a2277aadf9d853c64d52f57cd3dce5e67c) which is not part of the current stable branch. It is currently only part of the dev branch (soon to be 4.0). So you seem to be on the dev branch.

Given that OP 4.0 will be released very soon, I would advise you to stick to using the dev branch so that you can save yourself the work of upgrading from 3.0 to 4.0.

Without being a Windows user myself, if you intend to use the upcoming 4.0 release already, [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1474757/martin)'s advise is correct, you will need to install bower. The [bower](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bower) page explains how.